# PHP Capture return value from a evaluated function in PHP

Tags: php, selenium, eval

I am using facebook php-webdriver for my web app testing. There is a function in webdriver that works as below

```
$webdriver->wait($timeOut, $pollInterval)->until(
    //condition to wait
);
```

This "condition to wait" is passed as a method such as;

```
$val = WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::id("user"))
```

So the full code block is like;

```
$webdriver->wait($timeOut, $pollInterval)->until(
    $val = WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::id("user"))
);
```

I then have anther method such as;

```
function get($url, [few more params], $expectedCondition){
    //do some work here and execute below wait condition
    $webdriver->wait($timeOut, $pollInterval)->until(
        $expectedCondition //this executes fine
    ); 
}
```

I will call the above method as below;
    get ([other params], WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::id("user"))

As you see the last parameter above is a method call in itself that comes into my GET method. It'll execute properly as below

```
    $webdriver->wait($timeOut, $pollInterval)->until(
        $expectedCondition //this will basically executes WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::id("user")) properly
    );
```

However I can't get the return value after executing $expectedCondition.

eval() doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$return_value = $driver->wait()->until($expectedCondition)
```